# Python Import Module from Decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-decorators

I'm working on an application in Python 3, and what I'm doing is unconventional.

cx_Oracle is a difficult module to setup, and for my application is an optional dependency. What I would like to do is wrap the import of the module in a decorator, to place only above the functions that use it. This will keep from having to import at the top of my module and allow it to not be setup.

```
class Loader():
    def load_cx_oracle(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):

            # Additional code before import.

            import cx_Oracle

            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner

    @load_cx_oracle
    def function_using_cx_oracle(self):
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect()
```

However, when I try the above, I get `NameError: name 'cx_Oracle' is not defined`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`import` only binds the module name in the namespace where you use it.  if you do `import cx_Oracle` inside a function, the name `cx_Oracle` will only be available inside that function.

However, you can use `global` to make the assignment global.  Change your decorator to use:

```
global cx_Oracle
import cx_Oracle
```

Whether this approach is really the right one is debatable.  Depending on how your code is being used, it may be cleaner to just have a function that users call if they want to make `cx_Oracle` available, to use a try-wrapped import as Daniel's answer suggests, or to have the loading be defined by some external setting (e.g., a config file).

Comment: This solves my issue. I hoped to go with a decorator for these functions for a couple reasons. There is some missing configuration stuff left out of my example. This application will at times just run one of these functions. Basically it will be passed arguments to run just one function listed.

Comment: As @Dunes mentions, using `global` only works if the decorator is defined in the same module as the decorated functions.

Answer (score 8):

There a couple of problems with the accepted answer. The most important of which is that it runs the import logic each and every time the function is called. The second is that the decorator must be defined in the same module it is used in otherwise the decorator and the decorated will have different globals. You can directly access a function's globals through the `__globals__` attribute of the function. The code example first checks if module exists in the function's globals before executing the import logic. The example also uses the `functools.wraps` decorator to preserve doc strings, function name and also argument names when using things like `help(func)`.

```
from functools import wraps

def load_operator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if "operator" not in func.__globals__:
            # setup logic -- only executed once
            import operator
            func.__globals__["operator"] = operator
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class A:
    @load_operator
    def add(self, x, y):
        return operator.add(x, y)

    def subtract(self, x, y):
        return operator.subtract(x, y)

a = A()
try:
    a.subtract(1, 2)
except NameError:
    print("operator not yet loaded")
print(a.add(1, 2))
print(A.add)
```

Comment: Would this also prevent multiple imports from multiple function calls. For example, if you did include your decorator for `def subtract(self, x, y)` would it still only be loaded once, or separately for each function? I understand that the current answer does call for each function, but I was wondering specifically if yours could be modified to prevent that across functions in the same module.

Comment: Yes it would prevent multiple imports -- since functions declared in the same module share the same globals.

Comment: Running the import logic each and every time is nothing more than what you are doing by checking that "operater" is already in globals -- the first thing import checks is if the module has already been imported, in which case it's a simple name assignment.  Your second point, however, is the real issue -- so +1 for that.

Comment: @EthanFurman OP stated that he was doing stuff other than just the import. If was just the import then I agree the check would be pointless.

Comment: You are right that it only works in the same module.  In the OP's example, the decorator itself was defined not only in the same module but the same *class* as the decorated function, which I took to mean that cross-module use was not an issue (although this may be unrealistic).  In any case, I think using `func.__globals__` is even more dubious than using `global`, and if you have to do this it's better to use another approach entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an optional import, use try-except at the beginning of your module:

```
try:
    import cx_Oracle
except ImportError:
    cx_Oracle = None
```