# mypy throws an error for a decorator using a global variable

Tags: global-variables, python-decorators, mypy

I have this decorator:

```py
def load_tf(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        global load_model
        from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner
```

That I use only when I need something from `tensorflow` module.

The code works just fine but `mypy` throws a error message:

```py
@load_tf
def run_with_tf(...):
    my_model = load_model(...) # Name "load_model" is not defined mypy(error)
...
```

How to make peace with `mypy`?

Let me illustrate with a working example:

`snippet.py`

```py
def load_getcwd(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        global getcwd # comment this line to see the difference
        from os import getcwd

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner


@load_getcwd
def print_dir():
    print(getcwd())


print_dir()
```

Then `python3 snippet.py` **does** work, but mypy complains about `getcwd`.

However, if one comments line `global getcwd`, it **won't** work anymore!

Comment: Does this even work for python? Globals aren't passed on when you call a function... I think the only option is that you accept `load_model` as a parameter or some dirty hacking by assigning `load_model` into the globals of the module that used the `@load_tf` decorator...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018731/python-import-module-from-decorator, second answer in particular.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit*: **TLDR**: Show mypy that there *should* be the `load_model` function from keras without actually importing it:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

Mypy will think `load_model` exists but when this code is executed `TYPE_CHECKING` will evaluate to `False` and you won't import `load_model`.

*Edit*:

But if your `load_tf` decorator and the decorated function aren't in the same module you'll have a problem at runtime if you don't find a way to add the module to the globals of the decorated function. (If `load_tf` is in the same module as the function then it doesn't matter as they both use the same globals)

There's a simpler solution to get the globals of the function you're wrapping. A function stores a reference to its globals in the the [`__globals__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) attribute - you can use that to make `load_model` available in the function:

```
def load_tf(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        if "load_model" not in func.__globals__:
            from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
            func.__globals__["load_model"] = load_model

        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner
```